# Array possui valores, mas seu length é zero

Tags: javascript, json, array, objetos

Preciso iterar sobre esse `array`, no entanto, embora ele não esteja vazio o `length` dele retorna 0 como vocês podem ver, alguém sabe o motivo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O cenário é o seguinte: eu estou recebendo dados em JSON de uma API e iterando sobre os objetos para colocar os valores da propriedade que desejo neste único `array`. Eu tenho com iterar sobre ele agora, porém com tamanho 0 quebrou a lógica.

```
//apkikey
//base_url
var tags = [];
var keywordsId = [];


function tagsData(){
  var input_tags =  $('.chips').material_chip('data');

  input_tags.forEach(function(tag){
    tags.push(tag.tag);
  });
}

function findKeyWordId() {

  tags.forEach(function(tag){
    var url = base_url + 'search/keyword' + '?api_key=' + apikey + '&query=' + tag + '&page=1';

    $.getJSON(url, function(response){
      response.results.forEach(function(tag_obj){
        keywordsId.push(tag_obj.id);
      });
    });

  });

  console.log(keywordsId);
};

function searchMovies() {
tagsData();
findKeyWordId();

  console.log("Tamanho do array: " +  keywordsId.length);

    keywordsId.map(function(id){
    var movie_url = base_url + 'keyword/' + id  + '/movies' + '?api_key=' + apikey;

    $.getJSON(movie_url, function(results){
      console.log(results);
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que gera esse console.log?

Comment: excedeu o espaço aqui, mas tá disponível no no jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1srzcm8r/)

Comment: Esse `base_url` é publico? se sim qual é o valor?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o que estava dando dor de cabeça, não era nada mágico, mas sim o fato do JavaScript ser assíncrono, eu estava chamando as minhas funções de callback no momento errado então tinha uma percepção errada do que estava acontecendo.